# ASP.NET store image in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to store image to database by following code but it through the exception "NullReference exception". When I debug this code, 'postedFile' is null.....Thanks in advance

```
protected void btnAddUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userName = tbxUserName.Text;
    password = tbxPassword.Text;

    HttpPostedFile postedFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

    Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream;
    BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);
    byte[] bytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);

    string queryInsert = "insert into smart_shop.users(name,password,image) values('" + userName + "','" + password + "','" + bytes + "');";
    dbObject.QueryFeeder(queryInsert);
}
```

Comment: Simple UI with userName,Password and Image.for selecting image use FileUpload1......I'm trying this several time but after selecting image when I click btnAddUser it shows no file uploaded that means null I don't understand whats happening....... even FileUpload1.HasFile returns false

Comment: Are you sure `PostedFile` is null? I think your issue may be something else. Why do you think `PostedFile` is null?

Comment: Actually want to say FileUpload1.HasFile returns false despite selecting the image....thanks in advanced

Comment: No your issue is something else. Do a global search on your solution and see where else you are using `FileUpload1`. There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted and it should work.

Comment: Why I'm getting this error I don't understand what should I do now.After clicking button through exception in " string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);" line and when I move cursor in  postedFile it appears null and exception  is "NullReferenceException" Please help me

Comment: Do yourself a big favor: Create another simple asp application and put that exact code and watch it will work. Once you see it is working, then try and figure out why it is not working on this application. Surely you have done something to break it.

Comment: Another note: your SQL code is wide open to SQL injection. Learn about parameterised queries.

Comment: This code inside in updatepanel after removing updatepanel and script manager it works fine but also need updatepanel for removing page refresh

Answer (score -1):

Most probably, you need to add  enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form tag.

Example:
`<form id="Form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">`

Comment: Don't guess at questions which don't include enough details to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: It is very obvious if FileUpload1.PostedFile is null

Comment: Yeah or it's [inside an UpdatePanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267183/fileupload-postedfile-always-null-inside-updatepanel), or [it's a duplicate anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185656/fileupload-postedfile-is-always-null-unless-the-page-has-posted-back-at-least-on).